# Creating an alert or label text for no data on a Table View. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2, alert

I have a table and what I want to do is display an alert when the table results are empty. So I have the alert displaying when it is empty however it also displays when it is full. What am I missing???
In my ViewDidLoad:

```
    if appUsers.count < 1 {

    // create the alert
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No Jammers found", message: "Sorry there are no Jammers matching your search preferences at this time. Try tweaking your search preferences or try this search later! Hope you find who you are looking for! Happy Jamming! ", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    // add an action (button)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

    // show the alert
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

**Edit Code in number of rows**

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if appUsers.count < 1 {

        // create the alert
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No Jammers found", message: "Sorry there are no Jammers matching your search preferences at this time. Try tweaking your search preferences or try this search later! Hope you find who you are looking for! Happy Jamming! ", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        // add an action (button)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

        // show the alert
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    return appUsers.count
  } // no of rows
```

Comment: ended up doing a label to display my text.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably move this code out of `viewDidLoad`. The reason this is being displayed regardless of the condition is because when your view loads the number of users is always less than one until your query returns the actual amount of users. If you do this in number of rows in section, then the condition will accurately reflect your actual data.

Comment: I have tried it there as well and it is the same result. It appears if the users result is empty and full?

Comment: Are you reloading your table view after you get results?

Comment: in the viewdidload not after the alert? I have updated my code to show u how I called it in the numberOfRows. What am I missing?